# Finding the lowest value in the array

Tags: java, arrays, max, average, minimum

```
int min = temperature[0];
//Here, i have initialized the minium array. 
else if(temperature[i] < min) {
            min = temperature[i];
```

And here i have compared the values in the array. But as the initialization of min is 0. It is going to minimum value zero all the time. How do i fix it. Here is my whole code.

```
 int[] temperature = new int[12];
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    int min = temperature[0];
    int max = temperature[0];

    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < temperature.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the temperature:" + i);
        temperature[i] = kb.nextInt();
        counter += temperature[i];
        if (temperature[i] > max) {
            max = temperature[i];
        }
        else if(temperature[i] < min) {
            min = temperature[i];

        }
    }
    int average = counter / temperature.length;
    System.out.println("Displaying the average temperature:" + average);
    System.out.println("The lowest temperature is:" + min);
    System.out.println("The highest temperaature is:" + max);
    }
}
```

Comment: "*But as the initialization of min is 0. It is going to minimum value zero all the time.*" - Well then don't initialize it with `0`.

Comment: What data is actually in your array?

Comment: @MakotoThe data in the array is just the user input number for instance temperatures.

Comment: *as the initialization of min is 0*: it's not. It's initialized with temperature[0]. It's just that you initialize the minimum **before** the user has entered values, instead of doing it **after**.

Comment: As initial guess for a *min value* you should pick a high value, for example `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Otherwise your array elements have no chance to be lower than the initial guess. Note that there is `Collections.min(Arrays.asList(myArray))` and similar.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `else`, logically - if the value is less than the current minimum we want to update current minimum (regardless of the state of the current maximum). We can actually make it clearer using `Math.max(int, int)` and `Math.min(int, int)`. And, we can't default `min` and `max` to initial values without having read the input (unless we use unambiguously absurd values). Like,

```
int[] temperature = new int[12];
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < temperature.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the temperature:" + i);
    temperature[i] = kb.nextInt();
    counter += temperature[i];
    max = Math.max(max, temperature[i]);
    min = Math.min(min, temperature[i]);
}
int average = (int) (counter / (double) temperature.length);
System.out.println("Displaying the average temperature:" + average);
System.out.println("The lowest temperature is:" + min);
System.out.println("The highest temperaature is:" + max);
```

Otherwise, you **need *two*** loops. Finally, note you were using integer math in calculating `average`. You presumably want floating point math.

**Or**, even better, use [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) like

```
int[] temperature = new int[12];
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < temperature.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the temperature:" + i);
    temperature[i] = kb.nextInt();
}
IntSummaryStatistics iss = IntStream.of(temperature).summaryStatistics();

System.out.println("Displaying the average temperature:" + iss.getAverage());
System.out.println("The lowest temperature is:" + iss.getMin());
System.out.println("The highest temperaature is:" + iss.getMax());
System.out.println("The total of all values is:" + iss.getSum());
```

Comment: If you initialize `min` and `max` with the first array-element, the `if`-`else if` is actually correct, since at start `min == max`. And since `min` gets only smaller, while `max` gets larger, some value can either update `min` or upate `max`, but not both.

Comment: @Turing85 That's the "two loops" comment I was making.

Comment: You can do it with one loop and the `if`-`else if` :D But the `Math.min(...)`.`Math.max(...)` variant is more readable anyway

Comment: @Turing85 On reconsideration, I'd just use `IntSummaryStatistics`

Comment: I want to use very basic Java, as i am learning the language. But after getting some hint, I have made a modification in the source code. And i have used two loops as mentioned above. But the issue is not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to initialize min to the first value of your array, if the array had at least one value. You could also set it to Integer.MAX_VALUE if you really want.